# When leaving an apartment, how does the utilities disconnection work?

Tags: netherlands, rental, relocation, payment, utilities

When you leave a (rental) apartment in the Netherlands, you want to stop paying your utility bills, namely:

- Water
- LP gas & electricity (often/always go together)
- Municipal taxes
- Internet

How exactly does this work? Specifically, can you do this when you've already left, or do you need to do it earlier? Is there important information you need in order to complete the disconnection? Should you actually disconnect or can you transfer your contract/liability to the next tenant?

Answer (score 1):

Water, gas, electricity: If you have a direct contract with them (it does not go though the person/company you rent from), visit their website or phone them up and cancel your agreement. Depending on the company, there may be a notice periode. Have your customer number etc. ready.

You may also need the gas/water/electricity usage numbers, if they don't have them already or come to collect them. You can read them from the respective meters, and should keep them until you have paid the final bills.

You cannot transfer to the next tenant, but you can take the contract with you if you move location. If you move to another utility company, *the new one* can/will handle the transfer for you.

Answer (score 0):

As far as **Internet service** is concerned, some companies (e.g. KPN) require a full month's notice for disconnection. Also, if you were using a router they provided you with - they want it back. They should mail you a box, that you then place your router in and send back to them.

Also, it's not that easy to find the disconnection information on some websites; specifically, for KPN, cal 08000402 (they can speak English).

(Will add to this answer as I figure other utilities out.)